# How do you know the manpages name for a given package?

Tags: manpage

Take for instance the `python3-requests` package. I see that there is `/usr/share/doc/python3-requests` but I can't seem to figure out the manpages "name".

Given an installed package, is there a way to discover the manpages name for that package?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the manpage is contained in the package, then you should be able to see it when you list the contents of the package:

```
$ dpkg -L python3-requests | grep /usr/share/man
```

What you're possibly looking for however is the Python documentation of the module. Debian packages for Python module `foobar` are called `python*-foobar`. So to get the Python documentation for module `foobar`, you'd do

```
pydoc foobar
```

(or `pydoc2` or `pydoc3` depending what Python version they're for). So here:

```
pydoc3 requests
```

Comment: Ah ok good to know. In this case, it appears as though there is no manpage for `python3-requests`. Thanks!

Comment: What you're possibly looking for however is the *Python* documentation of the module. Debian packages for Python module `foobar` are called `python*-foobar`. So to get the Python documentation for module `foobar`, you'd do `pydoc foobar` (or `pydoc2` or `pydoc3` depending what Python version they're for).